# How to use Web Services with ASP.NET Identity in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, identity

I developed a project with `ASP.NET MVC`. In my project I have two kind of users: `1-User` and `2-Customer`.

I used ASP.NET Identity to Authorize users and I have method like this for login:

```
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel, string returnUrl)
{
    var loggedinUser = await _applicationUserManagerService.FindAsync(loginViewModel.Email, loginViewModel.Password);
    if (loggedinUser != null)
        await _applicationUserManagerService.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(loggedinUser.Id);

    var result = await _signInManagerService.PasswordSignInAsync(loginViewModel.Email, loginViewModel.Password, loginViewModel.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
    switch (result)
    {
        case Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInStatus.Failure:
            break;
        case Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            break;
        default:
            return View(loginViewModel);
    }
    return View(loginViewModel);
}
```

But I have a problem, I have to authorize `Customer` by `Web Service` and I don't know how to do it. Can I use `ASP.NET Identity`, or I should use Session ?

After login Customer can change pages and in each page I have to load some data from `Web Services`.

Is it secure to put data in cookie?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager`, which you use for user authentication, is just a facade over [Claim-Base Identity](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com.by/2013/12/using-claims-in-aspnet-identity.html).

To authorize user in application, you only need to create `ClaimsIdentity` and run `AuthenticationManager.SignIn` method.

Your code be can changed the following way:

```
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel, string returnUrl)
{
    ...

    //try to authenticate user via login and password
    var result = await _signInManagerService.PasswordSignInAsync(loginViewModel.Email, loginViewModel.Password, loginViewModel.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
    switch (result)
    {
        ...

        //try to authenticate customer via web-service
        case Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInStatus.Failure:
            //proxy-class to access your web-service
            CustomerServiceClient clientToService = new CustomerServiceClient();
            var customerData = clientToService.LoadCustomerData(loginViewModel.Email, loginViewModel.Password)

            ...

            ClaimsIdentity identity = CustomerIdentityHelper.CreateIdentity(customerData);
            AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = loginViewModel.RememberMe}, identity);
            break;
        default:
            return View(loginViewModel);
    }
}
```

According to your last question where to store user data, you can store frequently used data in claims, which by default are encrypted and stored in cookie (if cookie-based authentication middleware is added to application pipeline). But the volume of such data should not be too large. Otherwise you can use session or to query data from service each time.

Comment: thank you . I have just a qiestion . Isn't better to create another Login form ? because It might be user and Get Faild Result and in this way I dont need to check with Web service .

Comment: It depends on how you are going to allow users to authenticate. I just wrote how you can authorize users and customers in two different ways. Where to use this code depends on your application needs and UI.

Comment: an for last question , how can I Limit `customer` just for `Customer` Area ? because I dont want do allow customer to visit `Admin` area ?

Comment: You can use [ClaimsAuthorize("ClaimType", "ClaimValue")] attribute with controller or action to allow access to it only users with existed specified claim value. I advice to use RoleClaimType  for such reasons. See details by the following link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.roleclaimtype(v=vs.110).aspx